# Ter mais opções no action_send dialog

Tags: java, android

Estou usando o `action_send`, porém ele nao me da as opçoes de Whatsapp, facebook, e outras redes sociais. Apenas Gmail e Mensagem.

Código que estou usando é:

```
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "Enter your title here");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enter your description here");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

Como posso fazer para aparecer mais opçoes de aplicativos para eu compartilhar? Algo como isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mesmo tendo o facebook e apps de outras redes sociais instalados no aparelho, elas não aparecem?

Answer (score 0):

O uso mais direto e comum do [`ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) é enviar conteúdo de texto de uma atividade para outra. Por exemplo, o aplicativo pode compartilhar uma URL da página atualmente exibida como texto com qualquer outro aplicativo **que já tenha instalado no *smartphone***. Isso é útil para compartilhar um artigo ou site com amigos por e-mail ou redes sociais, porém as opção são fornecidas pelo Android. Basicamente o Gmail e Mensagem aparecem porque são nativos do Android.

Algo possível de fazer é [filtrar as opções que aparecem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for)<sup>(en)</sup>, por exemplo, remover todas as opções e deixar somente Whatsapp, facebook e Gmail, porém é importante lembrar que só aparecerão se já estiverem instalado no dispositivo.